# Android AVD Creation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm having serious problems creating an Android Virtual Device using Android Studio. I have tried using the AVD Manager within the Android Studio IDE, but I keep getting this message in a small dialog box: "studio quit unexpectedly." What could this mean. I've seen other discussions about this same problem that say to try running the AVD Manager from the command line. This allowed me to create the AVD, but I could never get it to run successfully. Am I missing some sort of plug-in that allows me to properly use the AVD Manager in Android Studio? What could be the cause of this? Is Android Studio just naturally buggy on Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

Try Genymotion instead, AVD seems to have issues.

Comment: Does Android/Google not know about this? I can't find anywhere that they have acknowledged/addressed this problem. It just seems that, if this was a problem on every platform, the Android people would be on it. They wouldn't need third party software (like genymotion) to have it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a known issue regarding Android simulator and virtualization, so take a look if the following message pops up in the console:

```
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: Failed to sync vcpu reg
emulator: Failed to sync HAX vcpu context
```

If that's the case, it's likely that you have one or more virtual machines running in your system. Try shutting then down and repeating the process. If you manage to run the simulator that way, you can turn those VM's on again after running the simulator... but the android simulator won't run as long as there are VM's running. Weird, but true :(